# jQuery - Find element by element path

Tags: jquery

I have a path of an element as below.

```
html:eq(0)>body:eq(0)>div#header>div#blueAreaCommon>div#titledescription>div.title>a:eq(0)
```

Now I need to change the text of that element. So I did as below.

```
$(document).find("html:eq(0)>body:eq(0)>div#header>div#blueAreaCommon>div#titledescription>div.title>a:eq(0)").html("Some text");
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any solution?

Thank you!

Comment: since you have so many element  id's why are you doing this

Comment: it can be as simple as `$('div#titledescription > div.title > a:eq(0)').html("Some text");`

Comment: I would simple do `$('#titledescription .title a:first-child').text('some text');`

Comment: @may not be the same if `a` is not the first child of its parent

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your comments and replies. `$(document).find("path-to-element")` is working fine as in my question. i had another error. that's why it was not working. thank you!

Comment: @user2909624 - do you understand the an ID is supposed to be unique in the document so using a complex path with multiple IDs in it is usually an inefficient way to find something and the browser is optimized for finding a single ID.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this in such a complex way.

Since ID's are unique on the HTML, you can target as this way:

```
$("#titledescription > .title > a.eq(0)").html("Your Content");
```

Comment: You might want to explain that ids are unique and that's why you can go this way.  You also might want to add `>` to mimic the direct child of the path.  Also should add `.eq(0)` like the original path had.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your comments and replies. `$(document).find("path-to-element")` is working fine as in my question. i had another error. that's why it was not working. thank you!

Comment: @user2909624: Your path is complex. You can try above mentioned way which is direct way to target